# writing binary value to an array

Tags: matlab

```
for n = 1:99
    k(n) = n;
    x_d(n) = n/100;    
    x_fp_temp=fi(x_d(n),1);

    x_fp_bin(n)=bin(x_fp_temp)
end
```

Hi i am trying to write binary value to array x_fp_bin(n) ,, but am getting error `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch`.can some one please help me out

Comment: The following code raises no error on my computer.

`n=99;k=(1:n)';x_d=k/100;x_fp_bin=bin(fi(x_d,1));`

Comment: You haven't shown the code for `fi` or `bin`, so it's very hard to say.  Also, you haven't specified which line of code causes the error message.

Comment: `fi` and `bin` are Matlab functions from the [Fixed-Point Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/toolbox/fixedpoint/)

Comment: @Aabaz: Ah, I see.  They're pretty badly-named, then!

Answer (score 2):

It is the line:

```
x_fp_bin(n) = bin(x_fp_temp);
```

that fails you. Basically it is because you are returning an array of chars (1's and 0's) and you can not put that directly into a one dimensional array. Either use an bigger array:

```
x_fp_bin(n,:) = bin(x_fp_temp);
```

or use cellstrs:

```
x_fp_bin(n) = {bin(x_fp_temp)};
```

Also, is there a reason why you are using a loop instead of using array notation?

```
bin_arr = bin(fi((1:99)'./100, 1));
```

Comment: +1 also if you decide to use loops, consider pre-allocating the variables

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, because you didn't write which line is giving you that error.

this line:

```
x_fp_temp=fi(x_d(n),1);
```

defines an array of `n x 1`

this:

```
x_fp_bin(n)
```

is a scalar value (i.e `1 x 1`)

it looks to me like you're trying to assign a vector to an array.

Comment: Actually when I run suri's code the error is raised by `x_fp_bin(n)=bin(x_fp_temp)` where the output of `bin(x_fp_temp)` is a 1x16 char array (1 and 0). But the code given in my above comment works fine.